# Programmatically instantiate a FeignClient for tests

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix

I have a dead simple FeignClient interface that I would like to "unit"/integration test  with a fake HTTP server, WireMock for example. The idea is to test the mapping with a sampled HTTP API response, **without configuring a whole Spring Boot/Cloud Context**.

```
@FeignClient(name = "foo", url = "${foo.url}")
public interface FooClient {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo/{foo-id}/bar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Bar getBar(@PathVariable("foo-id") String fooId);
}
```

Is there any way to programmatically instantiate this interface, like a Spring Data Repository through a `*RepositoryFactoryBean` ?

I see a `FeignClientFactoryBean` in the source code, but it is package protected, and it relies on an `ApplicationContext` object to retrieve its dependencies anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you ***can*** fake a real rest client using wiremock for testing purposes, but this is more about containing the functional test, that feign clients themself work. This is mostly not what you really want to test, because the actual need is to test your components using your client behave in a specified way.

The best practice for me is not to make live hard with maintaing a fake server, but mock the clients behavior with Mockito. If you use Spring Boot 1.4.0, here is the way to go:

Consider you have some `FooBarService`, which internally uses your `FooClient` to peform some `FooBarService::someAction(String fooId)`, which performs some business logic which needs to work with a foo with given id

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = App.class)
class FooUnitTest {

   @Autowired;
   private FooBarService fooBarService;

   @MockBean;
   private FooClient fooClient;

   @Test
   public void testService() {
      given(fooClient.getBar("1")).willReturn(new Bar(...));

      fooBarService.someAction("1");

      //assert here, that someAction did what it supposed to do for that bar
   }
}
```

At this point you first should clarify, what you expect the REST client to respond, when asking for "/foo/1/bar", by creating a mock for exactly that case and give the Bar object you expect to receive for that API, and assert that your application is in the desired state.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is the complete opposite of what I was searching for, sorry _"unit test"_ is misleading. I know I can mock beans within a unit test using a Spring Context, what I want is to create a `FeignClient` implementation programmatically _without_ having to configure a Spring Context. I want to test if my client's relative paths match, and if the JSON mapping works -- just like a persistence integration test with HSQLDB. The more I look at the source code, the more I think it's not possible without a Spring Boot/Cloud Context.

Comment: This is indeed impossible, since @FeignClient itself is a spring annotation. When you look into the spring source, you will see that the context is taking your declaration and configuring feign manually internally. You can do this with on your own and test against a fake HTTP server, but this would be a lot of work

Comment: It is possible with JPA or Cassandra repositories, which are annotated interfaces too. The difference is that Spring Data's FactoryBean classes are public, and cleanly decoupled from the Spring Context. They probably didn't bother to do it with `FeignClient` because underlying Feign is already a standalone project.